# should a non-database data class I need be created as a Rails 3 "model", or just a basic class in the /lib area?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-models

should a non-database data class I need be created as a Rails 3 "model", or just a basic class in the /lib area?

I want to build some classes to represent calculated domain objects.  So the fields won't reference a database table/column.  There will be also methods in the class that with the data.

Question - When generating these classes should these be just normal Ruby classes I put in the /lib area?  Or should I/can I use rails models for this (and generate with "rails g model ...")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tableless models should probably be kept in app/models. I have several that access APIs. [ActiveModel](http://railscasts.com/episodes/219-active-model) in Rails can help bring in some of the useful functionality of Active Record.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question..I had the same question a few weeks back.

I put those class under model directory. This is how I came up with that decision. The class that I wrote was completely related to a particular app no common features to share with anyone at-least at the moment. I also needed to use some of my existing models to query some data in that class. So I made it a class under model directory. I might be wrong but thats what I have done now.

In another case where I am using a certain api sets for a web and mobile app I am thinking of making the code which interfaces with the api into a gem. The thing to note here is that the api set is also part my system and it will only be used by my apps.

Answer (score 1):

Classes that don't map to database tables can still reside inside of app/models. Instead of extending your class from ActiveRecord::Base, you can simply declare your class without any extensions (or your own extensions).

The CanCan ability model is a good example of this. It resides in app/models/, however does not extend ActiveRecord::Base. More information on CanCan's ability model can be found here: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities

Also consider that code under lib/ will not reload in the development environment by default.